# Show error message when custom Ribbon button is disabled

Tags: ribbon, validation

I have a custom button added to SharePoint Ribbon. And there is EnabledScript attribute of the CommandUIHandler for the button. This attribute contains a javascript code to conditionally disable/enable the button. 
Can I set a tooltip message that show up when user moves the mouse over a button when it is disabled?

Comment: You can set the `ToolTipTitle` and `ToolTipDescription` of the [**`<Button>`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458366(v=office.15).aspx) element to show tooltip on your custom button and they show even when the button is disabled. Or do you want the tooltip to be shown _only_ if button is disabled.

Comment: Naveen, thanks for your comment. Yes, I would like to show it only if button is disabled. But if there is no way to do it I will just put more information to ToolTipTitle/ToolTipDescription.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML `title` attribute of your `custom button`. Set it dynamically on basis of whether it is enabled or disabled. You can bind `onmouseover` event to the button, where you will be resetting the `title` attribute dynamically.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure how I can specify any HTML attributes of the ribbon button. Do you have any example?